# How do display Menu and then game on Windows Phone 7 using XNA?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna

I've read a few books on Windows Phone 7 game development with XNA, and they all go directly how to work with sprotes etc but they dont tell how to make a game that starts with menu and then depending on what user clicked what to do. Is there a better way, than to do a variable that holds information on what state our game is in, Menu or game itself, and then Draw() method would draw according stuff? I thought there would be more separation of different type of games into different files, like in other programming languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [MSDN Game State Management (Mango, C#/VB)](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/game_state_management) code sample is a fantastic demonstration of a basic menu implementation with XNA. I suggest you download and examine the code.